# Expression Tree Cast in VisitMemberAssignment

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm Trying to cast a value inside ExpressionVisitors override of VisitMemberAssignment

```
protected override MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
{
    if (null == node.Expression)
    {
        return base.VisitMemberAssignment(node);
    }
    var targetExpression = this.Visit(node.Expression);
    var sourceType = node.Member.DeclaringType;
    var targetType = this.ConvertType(sourceType);
    return Expression.Bind(this.ConvertMemberInfo(sourceType, node.Member, targetType), targetExpression);
}
```

My issue is that Expression Target is of type Int32.
and the Node.Member Reflection info states that it needs an Enumeration of Enums.PhoneType.

Does anyone know how I can Cast the Expression Targets type to my enumeration?

**EDIT**

```
// trys to map type base 
protected Type ConvertType(Type type)
{
    return this._typeConverter.MapType(type);
}

protected virtual MemberInfo ConvertMemberInfo(Type sourceType, MemberInfo sourceMemberInfo, Type targetType)
{
    // TODO: Support overloaded members?
    return GetMemberWithAnyBinding(targetType, sourceMemberInfo).Single();
}

protected static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMemberWithAnyBinding(Type targetType, MemberInfo sourceMemberInfo)
{
  return Enumerable.Union(targetType.GetMember(sourceMemberInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic),
  targetType.GetMember(sourceMemberInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
}
```

Comment: Can you post here your `ConvertType` and `ConvertMemberInfo` methods as it's unclear what they actually do

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Hey I made some edits for what they do its not much,  I Know I have to convert the target expression into a enum from an Int32.  But when I use convert its still resolves to an int32 for some reason